# Powershell - how to present choice of which AD OU to run against?

Tags: powershell, multiple-choice

I'm not a scripter and I'm trying to figure out how to allow the user a choice of what OU to run a script against.

I have the following basic script that enumerates through an OU and lists out some basic user object info to a CSV file:

```
$ADUserParams=@{ 
'Server' = 'ServerDC' 
'Searchbase' = 'OU=ToBeDeleted,DC=domain,DC=com' 
'Searchscope'= 'Subtree' 
'Filter' = '*' 
'Properties' = '*' 
} 

#This is where to change if different properties are required. 

$SelectParams=@{ 
'Property' = 'SAMAccountname', 'CN', 'HomeDirectory'
} 

get-aduser @ADUserParams | select-object @SelectParams | export-csv "c:\temp\tempoutput_users.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
Get-content "c:\temp\tempoutput_users.csv" | select -Skip 1 | Set-Content "C:\temp\UserOutput.csv"
Remove-Item "c:\temp\tempoutput_users.csv"
```

However, I would like to instead present the script runner a choice to be able to select which sub-OU inside the "ToBeDeleted" OU to run the rest of the script against.

For instance, if there is an OU called "September2016" and an OU called "October2016" both inside the "ToBeDeleted" OU, I would like the script to ask the person "Which OU would you like to run against?" and give them a numbered choice like:

1. September2016
2. October2016

and then they make a selection and the script runs against that particular sub-OU only and gets the user object info in that selected OU.

I looked up a few sites on giving "choices" but it seemed more like a Yes/No choice and I got lost.

Can anyone point me to the right direction to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Select-Array
{
    Param
    (
        $Array
    )
    $Count = 0
    Write-Host "Select Item"
    foreach ($Item in $Array)
    {
        Write-Host "$Count. $Item"
        $Count ++
    }
    $Selection = Read-Host
    return $Array[$Selection]
}

$OU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase 'OU=ToBeDeleted,DC=domain,DC=com'  -Filter * -SearchScope OneLevel).DistinguishedName

$ADUserParams=@{ 
'Server' = 'ServerDC' 
'Searchbase' = $OU 
'Searchscope'= 'Subtree' 
'Filter' = '*' 
'Properties' = '*' 
} 

$SelectParams=@{ 
'Property' = 'SAMAccountname', 'CN', 'HomeDirectory'
} 

Get-ADUser @ADUserParams | select-object @SelectParams | export-csv "c:\temp\tempoutput_users.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
Get-Content "c:\temp\tempoutput_users.csv" | select -Skip 1 | Set-Content "C:\temp\UserOutput.csv"
Remove-Item "c:\temp\tempoutput_users.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you...it's close but the $OU gets all of the sub-OUs and therefore the searchbase is off...I'll need to play with grabbing that $OU array and asking with that function which to pick

Comment: Does:
-SearchScope OneLevel  
help or are they at the same level?

Comment: They are at the same level.  I get an error because the $OU array tries to pass everything to the searchbase.